# Calling Firefox methods through java

Tags: java, firefox, java-native-interface

This may seems like a strange question but please bear with me as it is going to be really helpful for some people later on :)

What I am trying to do is call `firefoxs'` methods through java. Specifically I want to be able to run the following:

```
package setwallpaper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class SetWallpaper {
    private static final String CMD = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\" \"file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg\"";
public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call `firefoxs'` right click > set as desktop background option on any image I call. I'm not sure if this is possible but If anyone knows how to do this I'd be very grateful :)

Comment: You might be able to hack this up through a crazy series of steps, but there are better ways to accomplish this.  You haven't said if this is Windows, Linux, BSD, Solaris, MacOS, or something else, nor whether you want to target more than one environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've managed to figure this out. (Windows by the way)

I figured out that firefox calls the win32 library directly and this allows for me to change the background through that. Instead of using firefox in any way I tried to call this library through java directly but java is really a pain in the ass to call c, c#, c++... libraries from. So instead a friend helped by doing it in c# (literally took 10 minutes). Now I am able to change the windows background programmatically through c# at boot each time.